# Directly call system command from SLURM/SGE

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics, slurm

I would like to call a system command (kat hist) straight from the sbatch (slurm/sge) command without the .sh script. Not sure something like this is possible?

---

This is what I am currently doing:

```
"sbatch -p %s -n %s -t %s ./kat_reads_call.sh %s %s %s %s/filter_10xReads.py %s %s" % arg_list
```

Where `.kat_reads.sh` just does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
kat hist -o $1 -m $2 -t $3 <($4 -1 $5 -2 $6)
```

---

The goal is something like this :

```
"sbatch -p %s -n %s -t %s kat hist -o %s -m %s -t %s <(%s -1 %s -2 %s)" % arg_list
```

---

This is the error I recieve:

```
sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.  The first
sbatch: error: line must start with #! followed by the path to an interpreter.
sbatch: error: For instance: #!/bin/sh
```

Comment: Your goal is not working? Why?

Comment: I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `--wrap` parameter of `sbatch`. You will need something like:

```
"sbatch -p %s -n %s -t %s --wrap \"kat hist -o %s -m %s -t %s <(%s -1 %s -2 %s)\"" % arg_list
```

Apply the proper escape sequence, as I don't know hich language is it.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for! Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean as far as "proper escape sequence" based on what language it is? I actually need to do this for a couple of tools such as "kat", "supernova", and "samtools".

Comment: This was actually the final format that did the trick for me though: `"sbatch -p %s -n %s -t %s --wrap='kat hist -o %s -m %s -t %s <(%s -1 %s -2 %s)'" % arg_list`

Comment: Sorry, I was on holidays. By "proper escape sequence" I meant that you have to embed quotes inside quotes. Every language offers you a different way to achieve that, so you must check the syntax rules of your language to know how to do it. At the essence, you must give your command to `sbatch` as a single parameter to the `--wrap` option.